# cannot set new password using django-graphql-auth

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

Graphene sends the email, but the url doesn't exist. How should I set up the token url for this?

I can't find docs on how to configure **urls.py** so that the link that it sends through the email works.

http://127.0.0.1:8090/activate/eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImtkZWVuZXl6eiIsImFjdGlvbiI6ImFjdGl2YXRpb24ifQ:1m2a0v:04V3Ho0msVn7nHuFW469DC9GBYuUz2czfsFai09EOyM

**settings.py**

```
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
     'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
     'JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN': True,
     'ALLOW_LOGIN_NOT_VERIFIED': True,
     'JWT_ALLOW_ARGUMENT': True,
     "JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES": [
         "graphql_auth.mutations.Register",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifyAccount",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.ResendActivationEmail",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.PasswordReset",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifyToken",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.RefreshToken",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.RevokeToken",
         "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifySecondaryEmail",
     ],
}
```

**schema.py**

```
class AuthMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    register = mutations.Register.Field()
    verify_account = mutations.VerifyAccount.Field()
    token_auth = mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    update_account = mutations.UpdateAccount.Field()
    resend_activation_email = mutations.ResendActivationEmail.Field()
    send_password_reset_email = mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail.Field()
    password_reset = mutations.PasswordReset.Field()
    password_change = mutations.PasswordChange.Field()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view to handle this url.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from graphql_auth.models import UserStatus

class ActivateView(View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            token = kwargs.get("token")
            UserStatus.verify(token)
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/some/error/url")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/activate/thankyou")
```

And in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path("activate/<str:token>", ActivateView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```